# Points on Galois conjugate curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C$ be a curve defined over a number field $F$ and let $C^{\sigma}$ be its Galois conjugate obtained by applying $\sigma \in Gal(F/\mathbb{Q})$ to the coefficients defining $C$. What can we say about the $L$-points of $C$ and $C^{\sigma}$ for arbitrary field $L$?  In particular, does $C$ have an $L$-point iff $C^{\sigma}$ does when $L$ is a finite Galois extension of function field of, say another curve $D$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I guess $L$ is an extension of $F$.  This is surely naïve, but can't you extend $\sigma$ to $L$, and then say that $x \in C(L)$ if and only if $x^\sigma \in C^\sigma(L)$?

Comment: Thanks!! Can we always do that for arbitrary $L$?

Comment: Yes:  extend arbitrarily to a purely transcendental extension $L'$ of $F$ inside $L$, and then use the axiom of choice to extend from $L'$ to $L$.

Comment: I see!! Thanks!!